# MediaCodec is giving a storeMetaDataInBuffers trace error

Tags: android, encoding, android-mediacodec

I'm getting on the logcat the next error while encoding via the MediaCodec in Android.

The actual encoding works fine and the output is produced correctly, so I can't really understand why I get this trace. Is it a harmless error trace, or is there something I'm missing?

**E/ACodec(6438): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.h263] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -1010**

Next is the code where I get the trace

```
final int BIT_RATE          = 4000000;
final int FRAME_RATE        = 30;
final int IFRAME_INTERVAL   = 5;
final String MIME_TYPE      = "video/avc";

final MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);

MediaCodec encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);

//---------------------------------
// NEXT LINE PRODUCES THE TRACE
encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
//---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's harmless, most devices show this. See Q12 at http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/.

This only tells that the first way of signaling surface encoding wasn't supported by the encoder, so it used some other ways of setting it up. (There are multiple ways for the MediaCodec/ACodec layer to tell the individual encoder about it.)

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer has indicated that the warning is quite harmless. Some additional information on the `log` and reasons behind the same

This trace in the log is indicating that the `encoder` is not supporting `storeMetadataInBuffers` on the **`output`** port. For an `encoder`, this mode could be supported on both `input` and `output` ports.

This mode is employed for `input` port to pass raw image data in `metadata` format i.e. pass only a reference to the `gralloc` handle which can employed by the `encoder` to access the data. This is employed by the `camera` and/or other `screen recording` applications to pass a reference to `YUV` data to the encoder.

The `metadata` mode was supported for `output` port also for potential encapsulation of output `bitstream` data. For example, when a `Miracast` or `WiFi-Display` session is active and the data being encoded is **secure** like a premium content, it becomes necessary to protect data between the `encoder` and `HDCP` encryption module, during which `metadata` format becomes handy. Not many `encoder`s support this mode and hence, you observe this warning.

Comment: Then is there any configuration flag that can be set to avoid this trace, or is the trace just informative?

Comment: @PerracoLabs.. It's just informative as it's part of the `Stagefright` framework. I think it can easily be ignored. Please note that the same print works for both `input` and `output` ports. Encoders should support this mode on `input` port for optimal usage.